# Create a User in Active Directory via Powershellscript

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-authentication

I wanted to create a script to create a User through it in Active Directory. I already created a one-liner, which creates the User correctly. But know I want the script to create a User with different inputs.

I created the code, but somehow it doesn't work, can anybody elaborate what I did wrong?

```
$name=$args[0]
$givenname=$args[1]
$surname=$args[2]
$userlogin=$args[3]
$loginold=$args[4]
$description=$args[5]
$phone=$args[6]
$mail=$args[7]
$password=$args[8]
$passwordexpire=$args[9]
$locked=$args[10]
$oupath=$args[11]

echo $name
echo $givenname
echo $surname
echo $userlogin
echo $loginold
echo $description
echo $phone
echo $mail
echo $password
echo $passwordexpire
echo $locked
echo $oupath

New-ADUser -Name $name -GivenName $givenname -Surname $surname -UserPrincipalName $userlogin -SamAccountName $loginold -description $description -OfficePhone $phone -EmailAddress $mail -AccountPassword (Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword") $password -PasswordNeverExpires $passwordexpire -Enabled $locked -path $oupath

pause
```

Error message:

```
New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\POwershell\Create_ad_user.ps1:27 char:18
+ New-ADUser -Name $name -GivenName $givenname -Surname $surname -UserPrincipalNam ...
+                  ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Press Enter to continue...: 
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>
```

Comment: does `echo $name` output something? Also, `-AccountPassword` doesn't look right.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling the script from the command line?  Also please take a look at [Powershell Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554301.aspx) they make things much easier than using `$args`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like AccountPassword isn't correct as you are prompting for it `(Read-Host -AsSecureString "AccountPassword")` then supplying it in `$password` directly afterwards.

When you've got a large amount of parameters to pass [splatting](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts/) is often a good idea as it makes everything much easier to read like so:

```
$Params = @{
    Name = $args[0]
    Givenname = $args[1]
    Surname = $args[2]
    UserPrincipalName = $args[3]
    SamAccountName = $args[4]
    Description = $args[5]
    OfficePhone = $args[6]
    EmailAddress = $args[7]
    AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $args[8] -Force
    PasswordNeverExpires = $args[9]
    Enabled = $args[10]
    Path = $args[11]
}

Write-Output $Params

New-ADUser @Params
```

Comment: Thank you fo your answer, and sorry for the big delay.

When trying your code, i get the following error:

 `ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At C:\POwershell\create_ad_user_eingabe_test1.ps1:10 char:59
+     AccountPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $args[8] -Force
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~`

seems like something with the Password is wrong again to me.